# System throws exception and display playerProfile.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, react-hooks

I would like to display `data` received in the Player Profile fields. Started with `name` field, it displays name data, but while trying to edit the `name` text field, system throws following exception, `TypeError: playerProfile.map is not a function`. I have wrapped the `fetch` call inside the arrow function. Can someone please advise on what is the root cause of this error.

*Note: At the moment I have received the value for `name` field only, need to display for other fields and still need to work on `handleSubmit()`*

`Detailed error message from console:`

```sh
Uncaught TypeError: playerProfile.map is not a function
    at Profile (Profile.js:34)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17034)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18610)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22157)
```

My Sample Code

---

```
const [playerProfile, setPlayerProfile] = useState([]);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
      }

      const onChange = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        setPlayerProfile({ ...playerProfile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      }


      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/profile')
            setPlayerProfile(res.data.playerProfile);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        }
        fetchData();
      }, []);

      return (
        <div className="register_player_Twocolumn_layout_two"> 
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="myForm">
          {
            playerProfile.map(({ id, image, name, email, position, privilege, password }) =>(
            <div>
            <div key={id} className="formInstructionsDiv formElement">
              <h2 className="formTitle">Player Profile</h2>
              <div className="register_profile_image">
                <input id="profilePic" name="photo" type="file"/>
              </div>
              <div className="previewProfilePic" >
                <img alt="" error="" name="previewImage" className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" src=""></img>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="fillContentDiv formElement">
              <label>
                <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="name" type="text" key={name} value={name} onChange={onChange}/>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="email" type="text"/>
              </label>
              <label>
                <div className="select" >
                  <select name="privilege" id="select">
                    <option value="player">PLAYER</option>
                    <option value="admin">ADMIN</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" name="password" type="password"/>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="submitButtonDiv formElement">
                <button type="submit" className="submitButton">Save</button>
            </div>
            </div>
              ))
            }
          </form>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: What happens when you log `playerProfile` before the return statement? What value/values do you recieve in the logs

Comment: `setPlayerProfile({ ...playerProfile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });` <- this looks like `playerProfile` is an Object not an Array. `.map` is a member of Arrays not Objects. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: @soccerway, what does the structure of `playerProfile` like like? If like @RossAllen has hinted at you data being an object, you better off using [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and mapping over that instead

Comment: Structure displays in network tab with data as follows `{"playerProfile":[{"name":"David","email":"david@testmail.com","phonenumber":null,"id":5,"privilege":"PLAYER","photo":"C:\\fakepath\\city.JPG","position":"FORWARD","updatedAt":"2020-05-25T11:02:16.000Z"}]}`

Comment: @iamcastelli  I have added the structure for reference..

Comment: @soccerway, See my answer that fixes your bug on updating state. Link to live sandbox reproducing the approach is provided. If you need more clarification, please shoot

Comment: @iamcastelli Could you please look my new question: https://stack overflow.com/questions/62038146/once-login-is-successful-how-to-navigate-and-display-nav-links

Comment: @soccerway, I did checkout the [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038146/once-login-is-successful-how-to-navigate-and-display-nav-links), and it relates to authorization. Like once the user is authenticated how you get to show them some features, Like dashboard Nav? I have an answer similar to that on [authetication and authorization here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61922681/3758602) that addresses that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR: Check the Sandbox

@soccerway, based on our comments pointed out as per typos in you approach, here is some code that attempts to fix them. The link to the [Live Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-to-playerprofilemap-is-not-a-function-ihmg9?file=/src/App.js)

#### SOME Context

1. When you define you `playerProfile` component state, you initialize it as an array, successfully update it from the server as an array but mess it up in the input `onChange` handler. Let's say you type <kbd>s</kbd> in the name input. With this...

`setPlayerProfile({ ...playerProfile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });`

...you are transforming the `playerProfile` form this array.

```
// Fetched playerProfile from the api.
playerProfile = [
 {
   name: "David",
   email: "david@testmail.com",
   phonenumber: null,
   id: 5,
   privilege: "PLAYER",
   photo: "C:\\fakepath\\city.JPG",
   position: "FORWARD",
   updatedAt: "2020-05-25T11:02:16.000Z"
 },
 // Extra profile put to have a solid example
 {
   name: "Goriath",
   email: "goriath@testmail.com",
   phonenumber: null,
   id: 5,
   privilege: "PLAYER",
   photo: "C:\\fakepath\\goriath.JPG",
   position: "MIDI",
   updatedAt: "2020-05-26T11:02:16.000Z"
 },
]

// To This Object
playerProfile = {
 0: {
   name: "David",
   email: "david@testmail.com",
   phonenumber: null,
   id: 5,
   privilege: "PLAYER",
   photo: "C:\\fakepath\\city.JPG",
   position: "FORWARD",
   updatedAt: "2020-05-25T11:02:16.000Z"
 },
 1:  {
   name: "Goriath",
   email: "goriath@testmail.com",
   phonenumber: null,
   id: 6,
   privilege: "PLAYER",
   photo: "C:\\fakepath\\goriath.JPG",
   position: "MIDI",
   updatedAt: "2020-05-26T11:02:16.000Z"
 },
 name: Davids"
}
```

Like you see, you cannot map over an object unless if you get its [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), in which case the approach would still be invalid by the second element in the object.

2. The other issue is that you are trying to update an object, and directly appending it to the array/object. If the update is successful, this will result into duplicate data save for the name. You need to find the old object in state and update it, then totally replace it. That would be fine if your data was normalized, like saved by keys initially. Something like this...

```
data= {
  playerProfilesById = {
    5: { // Player ID is the key
      name: "David",
      email: "david@testmail.com",
      phonenumber: null,
      id: 5,
      privilege: "PLAYER",
      photo: "C:\\fakepath\\city.JPG",
      position: "FORWARD",
      updatedAt: "2020-05-25T11:02:16.000Z"
   },
   6:  {
      name: "Goriath",
      email: "goriath@testmail.com",
      phonenumber: null,
      id: 6,
      privilege: "PLAYER",
      photo: "C:\\fakepath\\goriath.JPG",
      position: "MIDI",
      updatedAt: "2020-05-26T11:02:16.000Z"
    },
  },
  playerProfileIds=[5,6]
}
```

That way its easy to update `playerProfilesById`  with your approach, with the `[e.target.id]`(assuming you're passing the input tag it's  id) not `[e.target.name]`, while using the `playerProfileIds` to map over the items in the jsx.

---

3. However if you don't have control over the api data format, you could instead make sure you update your handler to receive an `id`(assuming the id is unique) from the onChange, use that id to find the profile in the array.

   - While finding, you could keep the element array Index, and use it to directly target and update the array. (*Commented out approach in handler*)
   - Or you could just map over the entire array and update the profile that changed, then use that data to eventually update state.

Below is the full approach.

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import axios from "axios";

/* Assuming your api returns data in the follwoing format... */
const fakeAPICall = () => {
  // CALL TO AXIO MUTED
  // const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/service/profile");
  // NOTE: Please normalize this data so it's easy to update
  // READ ABOUT: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape
  const data = {
    playerProfile: [
      {
        name: "David",
        email: "david@testmail.com",
        phonenumber: null,
        id: 5,
        privilege: "PLAYER",
        photo: "C:\\fakepath\\city.JPG",
        position: "FORWARD",
        updatedAt: "2020-05-25T11:02:16.000Z"
      },
      {
        name: "Goriath",
        email: "goriath@testmail.com",
        phonenumber: "1234345234",
        id: 6,
        privilege: "PLAYER",
        photo: "C:\\fakepath\\goriath.JPG",
        position: "MIDFIELDER",
        updatedAt: "2020-05-26T11:02:16.000Z"
      }
    ]
  };

  return { data };
};

const PlayerProfile = () => {
  // Note that your player profile is defined as an array in state.
  // Remember to always keep it that way when updating it.
  const [playerProfile, setPlayerProfile] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  // Pass the id to the handler so you will know which item id changing.
  const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    e.persist();
    let itemIndex;
    const targetPlayer = playerProfile.find((player, index) => {
      console.log({ player, id, index });
      itemIndex = index; // Track the index so you can use it to update later.
      return player.id === id;
    });
    console.log({ targetPlayer, id, e });

    const editedTarget = {
      ...targetPlayer,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    const tempPlayers = Array.from(playerProfile);
    tempPlayers[itemIndex] = editedTarget;

    /*
    // Alternatively:: you can just  map over the array if you dont want to track the index
    const tempPlayers = playerProfile.map((profile, index) => {
      return profile.id === id ? editedTarget : profile;
    });
    */

    setPlayerProfile(tempPlayers);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        // const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/products");
        const res = await fakeAPICall();
        console.log({ response: res });
        setPlayerProfile(res.data.playerProfile);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log({ "⚽: playerProfile": playerProfile });

  return (
    <div className="register_player_Twocolumn_layout_two">
      <h1>CAPTURE PLAYER PROFILE</h1>
      <p>Form to capture player Profile</p>
      <hr />

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="myForm">
        {playerProfile.map(
          ({ id, image, name, email, position, privilege, password }) => (
            <div key={id}>
              {/*2. Also put the key on the outer div in the map above */}
              <div className="formInstructionsDiv formElement">
                <h2 className="formTitle">Player Profile</h2>
                <div className="register_profile_image">
                  <input id="profilePic" name="photo" type="file" />
                </div>
                <div className="previewProfilePic">
                  <img
                    alt=""
                    error=""
                    name="previewImage"
                    className="playerProfilePic_home_tile"
                    src=""
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="fillContentDiv formElement">
                <label>
                  NAME
                  <input
                    className="inputRequest formContentElement"
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    // key={name} // Remove this key or renmae it to id. Since name changes on rerender, it confuses react that the key is different and forces the element to toose focus
                    value={name}
                    onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)} // Pass the ID form here.
                  />
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input
                    className="inputRequest formContentElement"
                    name="email"
                    type="text"
                  />
                </label>
                <label>
                  <div className="select">
                    <select name="privilege" id="select">
                      <option value="player">PLAYER</option>
                      <option value="admin">ADMIN</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input
                    className="inputRequest formContentElement"
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                  />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="submitButtonDiv formElement">
                <button type="submit" className="submitButton">
                  Save
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PlayerProfile />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**PS**: When you are mapping over items, each direct wrapper expects a unique `key` prop, that way react can know which component exactly changed to a avoid re-renders. In your approach, you're assigning the key to the input deep in the tree. Move it up to the outer most div wrapper.

Also make sure that whatever item you use as the key is unique, otherwise the items will keep loosing focus on updates if the key changes. For example in your code, the name is being changed but you are using it as the input. This results into a new key meaning you are working on a new element, eventually loosing focus on that input.

Comment: ...I really appreciate your help. Thank you. Now the error is gone, but if i add `onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}` i am unable to edit the name field displaying David

Comment: Wait a minute, am adding some explanation to the code. But it possibly because maybe you forgot you still got you key={name} set of the name input. Which makes react assume it's just another element. Did you check out the sandbox? Does it exhibit the same behavior? Like the field wont update?

Comment: Also can I ignore this error/ Warning logged in console >> : Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Profile (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:22)
    in Switch (at App.js:20)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter

Comment: If you are short of time. Move on :). But its best you address it thoug. That is caused by the async `api` request being made by the component then it unmounts whilst still going on in the background. It causes weird bugs especially if the list is too big. But the good thing axios has a [cancellable](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) where you can cancel the request inside the useEffect return callback function.

Comment: Sandbox link looks really good, but when use `onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}` i cannot edit and I have removed key={name} and moved the key attribute to top as suggested

Comment: When i use >> `onChange={handleChange}` while removing the name value by backspace or delete, it gets removed quickly but i can edit the field...still this also not looking good as i need to type whole value again..

Comment: Are you saying you the sandbox is not working for you or the changes you made to your code did not work. Sorry am asking this, am trying to figure out if either you are checking the wrong box or having a tricky time making updates to your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214642/discussion-between-iamcastelli-and-soccerway).

Comment: I have posted my changes in discussion channel

Comment: @soccerway, it looks like the typo is here `name={name}`, that should instead be `name="name"`.  I created another file in the sandbox [Attempt.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-to-playerprofilemap-is-not-a-function-ihmg9?file=/src/Attempt.js), that matches reproduces you state and that update your fixes the issue.

Comment: Fantastic help, accepted and upvoted the answer, clarified each section clearly ...

Comment: Glad you finally figured it out. Happy coding. PS, if you normalize that data though. It will save you some headache.

Comment: Could you please have a look when you get time.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492503/react-hooks-how-can-we-pass-a-selected-option-from-material-ui-dialog-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of your problem

```
<label>
  <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" 
   name="name" type="text" key={name} value={name} 
   onChange ={onChange}/>
</label>
```

The value "name" of the name property of the input tag is not in the array of playerProfile.
I think it should be:

```
<label>
      <input className="inputRequest formContentElement" 
       name={name} type="text" key={name} value={name} 
       onChange ={onChange}/>
</label>
```

that means your problem should be here

```
setPlayerProfile({ ...playerProfile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

playerProfile was an array, but the above line set's it to an object that's y it's throwing the error

This might work:

```
setPlayerProfile([ ...playerProfile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value ]);
```

Comment: I have given the name as the text field for the name field. That doesn't help

Comment: that means your problem should be here 

setPlayerProfile({ ...playerProfile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

playerProfile was an array, but the above line set's it to an object that's y it's throwing the error