# Once login is successful, how to navigate and display nav links

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

When login is successful, I would like to display the following Navigation Links based on following privileges. 
Display `Profile` nav link based on res.data.loginData[0].privilege === `"PLAYER"`. Display `Profile, Register` nav link if res.data.loginData[0].privilege === `"ADMIN"`.

Without login, when a user access the site, we should be displaying `Home, Login and Aboutus` pages only.

Being a beginner in this space, I am not sure if it implemented like this, please advise. 
[image]

`Login.js`

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/login', { email , password });
        setLoginData(res.data.loginData); 
          if (email === res.data.loginData[0].email && password === res.data.loginData[0].password) {
            setError(false);
            setHelperText('Login Successfully !');
            if(res.data.loginData[0].privilege === "PLAYER"){

            }
        } else {
            setError(true);
            setHelperText('Incorrect Email or Password..!')
          }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  };
```

`Navigation.js`

```
const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <nav className="siteNavigation_nav_links">
                    <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/profile">Profile</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/register">Register</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_login_link" to="/login">Login</NavLink>
                    <NavLink className="mobile_login_link" to="/aboutus">About us</NavLink>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navigation;
```

`App.js`

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const App = () => ( <BrowserRouter>
  <>
    <Navigation />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/aboutus" component={Aboutus} />
    </Switch>
  </>
</BrowserRouter>)
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "tabs", your `NavLink`s? Can you be more specific with what your expected result should be?

Comment: Yes, nav links, I have updated my question.Sorry for using different terminology

Comment: Are you using any sort of "global app state"? I.E. anything that the `Login` component can set that either `App`/`Navigation` can use or receive as a prop? Basically you'll need to get the role/privilege value to `Navigation` and conditionally render the links you want.

Comment: I don’t think I am having a global state at the moment.

Comment: I suggest you to use "Search" function of this site (this question was answered so many times) or directly check official documentation (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

Comment: Can we use localStorage set for Privelege and use that in App.js, but if get that localStorage value how do I use in Route ?

Comment: @soccerway, this answer on [authorization and authentication here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61922681/3758602) might be of help. It follows the same approch of never rendering some features if a permission is not met. A live sandbox is also [available here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-authentication-authorization-djl49?file=/src/App.js), that you can tweak around and get the idea.

If it's not helpful, please let me know and I will try to recreate your use-case. But first look through it.

Comment: @iamcastelli I saw the sandbox url, it is working great and seems very efficient one, but I am not able to understand some of the areas. A simple one would be really helpful.

Comment: Okay, let me add you a detailed an answer. Just gimme me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Conditionally render your `NavLinks` in the `Navigation` component. [Checkout the Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/permission-based-navbar-repro-wu9dx).

---

**SOME Context.**

@soccerway, Since this question could be answered with the same approach in a [previously answered one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61915523/creating-routes-using-permissions/61922681#61922681), for brevity, I recycled [this Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-authentication-authorization-djl49?file=/src/App.js), with a few minor changes to try and reproduce your case wiht the following assumptions...

1. It looks like you are using local state with `useState` on logging in based on this statement `setLoginData(res.data.loginData)`, but since your component might be unmounted by the Navbar given the fact that you are not having another Navbar or a dashboard and your users are bound to be moving back and forth easily, unmounting that component will result in the app loosing that state. It's much better to use higher up state management keeping the Auth and Privilege data between pages. You could use [React's Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and access it with [`useContext hook`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) or use [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) and wrap session data around the entire app. Once the user is logged in, save the app state in context or a store and retrieve it in whichever component needs to have that permission/privilege condition. In my [case, I use the context api](https://codesandbox.io/s/permission-based-navbar-repro-wu9dx?file=/src/AuthContext.js) api, and store the user-id in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).(You can use whatever session storage you want.)
2. Since I don't have access to your api, I created a simple [`fake Auth API`](https://codesandbox.io/s/permission-based-navbar-repro-wu9dx?file=/src/AuthContext.js), and to cover the `handleSubmit`. In the `AuthProvider`, I assumed the data you are getting from the server in this line `res.data.loginData[0].privilege === "PLAYER"` to be of the following format, but it can be anything.

```js
// Sample API FORMAT: Note this is normalized not array like -> loginData[0]
const users = {
  "player-1": {
    id: "player-1",
    username: "Player One",
    // permissions: ["view-profile"], // Alternatively, you could have permission logic
    privilege: "PLAYER" // Fetched by => res.data.loginData[0].privilege === "PLAYER"
  },
  "admin-1": {
    id: "admin-1",
    username: "Admin One",
    // permissions: ["view-profile", "register-user"],
    privilege: "ADMIN"
  }
};

// NOTE: The authenticated user is saved in context as currentUser,
// and the login state saved as isLoggedIn 

// Sample login Page
const LoginPage = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();
  const { isLoggedIn, login } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
  const { pathname } = from;

  let handleSubmit= userId => {
    // login is to the fake Api, but yours could be to an axios server.
    login({ userId, history, from });
  };

  return isLoggedIn ? (
    "you are already logged in"
  ) : (
    <div className="login-btns">
      {pathname !== "/" && (
        <p>You must log in to view the page at {pathname}</p>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => handleSubmit("player-1")}>Player Logs in</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleSubmit("admin-1")}>Admin Logs in</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

With your data readily accessible in all components via context, you can use it to translate the privilages into conditions to render the components. `Tip` *Name conditions related to the views you are rendering not the api, since it changes a lot*. You could retrieve the privilages from the context in whichever descendant component you wish to conditionally render as follows

```js
const { currentUser, isLoggedIn } = useContext(AuthContext);
const privilege = currentUser?.privilege || [];

// Create View conditions based on the privilages. You can be fancy all you want :)
const canViewProfile = privilege === "PLAYER" || privilege === "ADMIN";
const canRegisterUser = privilege === "ADMIN";
```

You could use this logic directly in your `Navigation` component but chances are high, some Routes and Switch will depend on this logic for conditional redirection. So it's best to avoid repetition, to keep it in the siblings' parent, or even compute it in the context/store. (Tip: *Trying to maintain the same related condition in many different places bites especially without TypeScript*).

In my case, I pass the conditions to the `Navigation` and `Pages` via props. See the `AuthedComponents ==== to your App component` below

```
// This is similar to your App component
const AuthedComponents = () => {
  const { currentUser, isLoggedIn } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const privilege = currentUser?.privilege || [];

  // Generate conditions here from the privilages. You could store them in the context too
  const canViewProfile = privilege === "PLAYER" || privilege === "ADMIN";
  const canRegisterUser = privilege === "ADMIN";

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <h1>{` ⚽ Soccerway `}</h1>
        <UserProfile />

       {/* Pass the conditions to the Navigation. */}
        <Navigation
          isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
          canViewProfile={canViewProfile}
          canRegisterUser={canRegisterUser}
        />

        <hr />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about-us">
            <AboutUsPage />
          </Route>

          {/* You can conditionally render hide these items from the tree using permissions */}
          <Route path="/profile">
            {/* Passed down the conditions to the Pages via props to be used in redirection */}
            <ProfilePage canViewProfile={canViewProfile} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/register-user">
            <RegistrationPage canRegisterUser={canRegisterUser} />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/">
            <HomePage />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

In the Navigation component, use `isLoggedIn` prop to either show the login `NavLink` item or the (Profile and Registration pages) since they are mutually exclusive. Conditionally render privilege based NavLinks with the computed props.

```
/* You could get these props from the auth context too... if you want */
const Navigation = ({ isLoggedIn, canViewProfile, canRegisterUser }) => (
  <ul className="navbar">
    <li>
      <NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="active-link">
        Home
      </NavLink>
    </li>
    {/* Check if the User is Logged in: Show the Login Button or Show Other Nav Buttons */}
    {!isLoggedIn ? (
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/login" activeClassName="active-link">
          Login
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    ) : (
      // Now, here consitionally check for each permission.
      // Or you could group the different persmissions into a user-case
      // You could have this as s seperate navbar for complicated use-cases
      <>
        {canViewProfile && (
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/profile" activeClassName="active-link">
              Profile
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        )}
        {canRegisterUser && (
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/register-user" activeClassName="active-link">
              Register
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        )}
      </>
    )}
    {/* This is a public route like the Home, its viewable to every one  */}
    <li>
      <NavLink to="/about-us" activeClassName="active-link">
        AboutUs
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
);
```

In the components, if the user does not meet the permissions/privileges, forcefully redirect them to the login page.

```
// Example usage in the Profile Page
const ProfilePage = ({ canViewProfile }) => {
  return canViewProfile ? (
    <>
      <h2>Profile</h2>
      <p>Full details about the Player</p>
    </>
  ) : (
    <Redirect from="/profile" to="/login" />
  );
};
```

Comment: If you need more clarification. Please leave reach out. Happy coding

Comment: I have installed `npm install --save react-auth-context` but still, Module not found: Can't resolve 'AuthContext' in 'C:\Project\soccerpep\src\components'

Comment: Did you create the AuthContext, or import it?  [Something like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/permission-based-navbar-repro-wu9dx?file=/src/AuthContext.js)

Comment: Added `import AuthContext, { AuthProvider } from 'AuthContext';` and tried with import AuthContext, { AuthProvider } from './AuthContext';

Comment: And did you wrap your app in a Provider, imported from that context `
const App = () => (
  <AuthProvider>
    <div className="App">
      <AuthedComponents />
    </div>
  </AuthProvider>
);`

Comment: @soccerway, did you visit the docs, on context, [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) section to be precise?

Comment: No need `react-auth-context`. The Context is a built in `react` api [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You create it with [`React.createContext(defaultValue);`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext), and assign it to a variable, you export a [Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) that you wrapp around the ancestor component, say the root App component in the tree, pass it the values you need to be accessible anywhere in the tree, and consume those values with the [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: May I know where should i need to add the `const App = () => ( <AuthProvider> <div className="App"> <AuthedComponents /> </div> </AuthProvider> )` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214783/discussion-between-iamcastelli-and-soccerway).